# What is a proper way to validate consumable IAP with Apple server?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

From iOS7 Apple deprecated transactionReceipt property of SKPaymentTransaction instance, and now we have one big receipt contained everything. In my app I have several consumable purchases. My code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;

           ...
    }

}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
//    [self sendRecieptToServer:transaction.transactionReceipt]; // deprecated
    [self testMainReceipt];
    [self deliverPurchaseNotificationFirIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)testMainReceipt {
    NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
    NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];

    [self sendRecieptToServer:receipt]; //look at the 'status' field and determine whether a good purchase or not
}
```

From Apple response I see 'in_app' filed with an array, containing always 1 item - my most recent purchase, no matter how many times I made purchases before.
Am I right that this how consumable purchases work? And I'll always get array with 1 item and 'status' field for this most recent purchase? Or there its better way?

Comment: Well, it should not contain any item as long as 'finishTransaction' was called.
But as a firesafe, I prefer to verify the transaction_id (saved in my db with a flag) to check whether this item was already credited or not. 
Just to confirm, is this happening in Production environment?

Comment: @Sanniv for now this is happening in sandbox. "it should not contain any item as long as 'finishTransaction' was called" - you mean new item in receipt? But it's there, no matter before or after finishTransactio:n call I check the receipt.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You'll need to buy these items every time you want them, and you can't download them again for free. If you remove and reinstall an app, or install an app on a new device, you might lose your consumable purchases. For example, if you install a game on your iPod touch that you started playing on your iPhone, the game levels sync, but extra health or experience points you bought on your iPhone don't sync.

Consumable Products can be Game Currency,Extra Health,Extra experience points.

Consumable Products can't be restored,& also appear once in receipt.

You can find more details [link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202023).
you can also check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2).

Comment: I can't properly understand this part - "appear once in receipt.". Does this means that in receipt I'll always see 1 item - my most recent purchase, no matter how many times I made purchases before? If yes - where in documentation stated this?

Comment: Yes,You can find it in apple doc. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2

Comment: Consumable products subscriptions appear in the receipt after being purchased but are removed the next time the receipt is updated. All other types of products have an entry in the receipt that isn’t removed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW16

Comment: Thank you @Dhruv Dalwadi. Suppose the user buys the consumable product "A" and, due to network outages, the purchase can't be immediately verified with the server and the corresponding transaction remains pending (not finished). Then suppose the user buys again another "A" product for the second time: is the receipt of this second purchase appended to the "global" receipt? When I'll try to validate the receipt for the two pending transactions will I receive positive results for both?

Answer (score 0):

You can go for *appStoreReceiptURL* method and if it is not available (on older systems), you can fall back to validating the transactionReceipt property of an SKPaymentTransaction object with the App Store.

For details, see [Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1).
Refer:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2